# Electric Furnace Temperature Theory

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, electricity, temperature

I am designing a small melting furnace using `120VAC` with an ideal maximum current of `10A`. I'll be using Kanthal A-1 resistance wire. The supplier I'm likely to use for the wire has the resistance of the wire listed per foot. For example, `20 AWG` Kanthal A-1 has a listed resistance of `0.817 Ohm / ft.`.

With this information, I can use `V = IR`, `P = IV` to work out the lengths required for each gauge of wire to achieve a maximum power draw of `1200W`. For example, `20 AWG` wire would need to be between 14 and 15 ft. long.

I have a good understanding of these calculations. Assuming that I'm doing them correctly, of course.

My question really begins here: I am having doubts about whether or not I'll actually be able to hit a particular furnace temperature to melt my desired metals. If I reach back into the memories of my physics classes from school, I remember that energy can only be transferred from higher energy states to lower energy states. In other words, a hot wire will transfer heat to its surroundings if the wire has more heat energy than its surroundings.

*Assuming my wire is "consuming" `1200W`, is there a point at which the wire will no longer be able to transfer heat to the furnace (and therefore cause the furnace to reach a maximum temperature)? Or is **any** temperature theoretically possible for any wattage given enough time and thermal insulation?*

Here is what I can come up with when thinking about this question to myself:

1. *On the one hand, there **is** a maximum furnace temperature because a certain current level can only yield a certain wire temperature. Temperature is correlated with heat energy and as the furnace heats up, the heat energy of the wire and the heat energy of the furnace will slowly get closer to equilibrium. At some point, the wire can no longer transfer heat energy to the system and a maximum temperature is reached.*
2. *On the other hand, there is **no** maximum temperature for the furnace (except for the melting point of the Kanthal A-1 wire). Yes, the wire is transferring heat energy from the wire to its surroundings. However, there is no equilibrium because electricity is constantly flowing through the wire. Energy is constantly being added to the system and that energy must go somewhere. In this case, because it's a furnace, the energy will be transferred as heat. Therefore, given enough time and enough insulation (assuming I don't lose heat faster than I can replace it), there is no maximum furnace temperature.*

To me, point number 2 seems to be the most reasonable reasoning. I'm hoping someone can confirm or deny this or maybe explain in a different way.